# Express js login system

Tags: javascript, express, user-interface, authentication

I have just finished building a login system. There is one thing that does not work no matter how I try. When the user is not logged it the `register` and `login` buttons are visible. But when I do log in the `logout` button does not appear nor do the other two disappear. This is the code:

`body
    div.navbar
        ul
            li
                a(href='/') Home
            if !user
                li
                    a(href='/users/register') Register
                li
                    a(href='/users/login') Login
        ul.right-side
            if user
                li
                    a(href='/users/logout') Logout`

What I am trying to accomplish is that the `login` and `register` buttons should disappear while the user is `logged in`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When the User did login , the variable `user` is settled to `true` globally ?

Comment: it is set in my `app.js` like this: 
`app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
      res.locals.user = req.user || null;
      next();
})`

Comment: I first, when do a login, I put the informations in session `req.session.isLoggedIn = true;  req.session.userInf = user; ` after, I expose session to views like `app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
  })` , and use `if session.isLoggedIn `in the view layer.